# How can I prevent these values of color and stocks to be duplicated when I add more sizes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Users can add more text fields of size, color, and stocks. If I'll add more sizes, the values for the color and stocks will duplicate from what was first entered.

Expected output:

> **1st Size : small**
>
> color: red, stocks: 10
>
> color: green, stocks: 3
>
> **2nd Size: medium**
>
> color: white, stocks: 3
>
> color: red, stocks: 6 the sizes field.

What it currently does is in the 2nd size, it will just duplicate whatever value was entered from the first size. How can I fix this? Thank you.

How can I combine the indexes of the colorList loop and sizeList loop to avoid the duplicates of the value of the textfields?

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-2-add-more-size-ddqqo?file=/demo.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

import { TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState();
  const [sizeList, setSizeList] = useState([{ size: "" }]);
  const [colorList, setColorList] = useState([{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);

  //sizes
  const handleServiceChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setSizeList(list);
  };

  const handleServiceRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setSizeList(list);
  };

  const handleServiceAdd = () => {
    setSizeList([...sizeList, { service: "" }]);
  };

  // color
  const handleColorChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...colorList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setColorList(list);
    // console.log(colorList);
  };

  const handleColorStocksChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...colorList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setColorList(list);
    // console.log(colorList);
  };

  // const handleColorChange = (e, index) => {
  //   const { value } = e.target;

  //   const arr = [...colorList]; //Shallow copy the existing state
  //   arr[index].color = value; //Update the size to the selected size
  //   console.log(arr[index].value);
  //   setColorList([...arr]); //Set the updated array to be the new state
  // };

  // const handleColorStocksChange = (e, index) => {
  //   const { value } = e.target;
  //   console.log(value);
  //   const arr = [...colorList];
  //   arr[index].colorStocks = value;
  //   // console.log(arr)
  //   setColorList([...arr]);
  // };

  const handleColorRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...colorList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setColorList(list);
  };

  const handleColorAdd = () => {
    setColorList([...colorList, { color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Product: ", productName, "size: ", sizeList, colorList);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          label="Product Name"
          name="name"
          type="text"
          id="productName"
          value={productName}
          onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        {sizeList.map((singleSize, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <TextField
              label="Size"
              name="size"
              type="text"
              id="size"
              required
              value={singleSize.size}
              onChange={(e) => handleServiceChange(e, index)}
            />
            {colorList.map((singleColor, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <TextField
                  label="color"
                  name="color"
                  type="text"
                  id="color"
                  required
                  value={singleColor.color}
                  onChange={(e) => handleColorStocksChange(e, index)}
                />
                <TextField
                  label="Stocks"
                  name="colorStocks"
                  type="text"
                  id="colorStocks"
                  required
                  value={singleColor.colorStocks}
                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index)}
                />
                {colorList.length !== 1 && (
                  <Button onClick={() => handleColorRemove(index)}>
                    Remove
                  </Button>
                )}
                <br />
                {colorList.length - 1 === index && (
                  <Button onClick={handleColorAdd}>Add Color</Button>
                )}
                <br /> <br />
                {/* add or remove sizes */}
              </div>
            ))}
            {sizeList.length - 1 === index && (
              <Button type="button" onClick={handleServiceAdd}>
                Add size
              </Button>
            )}
            {sizeList.length - 1 === index && (
              <Button type="button" onClick={() => handleServiceRemove(index)}>
                Remove Size
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}

        <br />
        <Button type="submit">Submit </Button>
      </form>

      <div className="output">
        <h2>Output</h2>
        <h3>Sizes:</h3>
        {sizeList &&
          sizeList.map((singleSize, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>{singleSize.size && <li>{singleSize.size}</li>}</ul>
          ))}

        <br />
        <h3>Color:</h3>
        {colorList &&
          colorList.map((singleSize, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>
              {singleSize.color && (
                <li>{singleSize.color + " - " + singleSize.colorStocks}</li>
              )}
            </ul>
          ))}
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Also in: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/sl41p5/handling_dynamic_textfields_values_are_duplicated/

Comment: What is your expected behavior? if anyone clicks on ADD SIZE button, it needs to add those three text fields?

Comment: @Prana yes, you're right

Comment: In your code sandbox code, it works perfectly. Isn't it?

Comment: @Prana no, since every time I'll enter in the fields `color` and `stocks` it will just be duplicated.

Comment: What is the purpose of add color?

Comment: @Prana so I could input more a variety of colors. My problem was that if I'll enter a color in the first size like 'yellow`. In the second size, the field of `color` will also be `yellow`. It kind of just copies whatever color was inputted in the field

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need an array of inputs, you need to maintain the states in that order.
See my updated sandbox [code https://codesandbox.io/s/form-2-add-more-size-forked-yvrgg?file=/demo.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-2-add-more-size-forked-yvrgg?file=/demo.js)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

import { TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState();
  const [sizeList, setSizeList] = useState([{ size: "", colorList: [{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }] }]);
  const [colorList, setColorList] = useState([{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }]);

  //sizes
  const handleServiceChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list[index] = { ...list[index] }; // copy the item too
    list[index][name] = value;
    setSizeList(list);
  };

  const handleServiceRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setSizeList(list);
  };

  const handleServiceAdd = () => {
    setSizeList([...sizeList, { service: "", colorList: [{ color: "", colorStocks: "" }] }]);
  };

  // color
  const handleColorChange = (e, index, innerIndex) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list[index].colorList[innerIndex][name] = value;
    setSizeList(list)
  };

  const handleColorRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...colorList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setColorList(list);
  };

  const handleColorAdd = (index) => {
    const list = [...sizeList];
    list[index].colorList.push({ color: "", colorStocks: "" });
    setSizeList(list)
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Product: ", productName, "size: ", sizeList, colorList);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          sx={{mb:2}}
          label="Product Name"
          name="name"
          type="text"
          id="productName"
          value={productName}
          onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
          required
        />

        {sizeList.map((singleSize, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <TextField
              label="Size"
              type="text"
              name={`size${index}`}
              id={`size${index}`}
              required
              value={singleSize.size}
              onChange={(e) => handleServiceChange(e, index)}
            />
            {singleSize.colorList.map((singleColor, innerIndex) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <TextField
                  label="color"
                  name="color"
                  type="text"
                  id="color"
                  required
                  value={singleColor.color}
                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index, innerIndex)}
                />
                <TextField
                  label="Stocks"
                  name="colorStocks"
                  type="text"
                  id="colorStocks"
                  required
                  value={singleColor.colorStocks}
                  onChange={(e) => handleColorChange(e, index, innerIndex)}
                />
                {colorList.length !== 1 && (
                  <Button onClick={() => handleColorRemove(index)}>
                    Remove
                  </Button>
                )}
                <br />
                {colorList.length - 1 === index && (
                  <Button onClick={()=>handleColorAdd(index)}>Add Color</Button>
                )}
                <br /> <br />
                {/* add or remove sizes */}
              </div>
            ))}
            {sizeList.length - 1 === index && (
              <Button type="button" onClick={handleServiceAdd}>
                Add size
              </Button>
            )}
            {sizeList.length - 1 === index && (
              <Button type="button" onClick={() => handleServiceRemove(index)}>
                Remove Size
              </Button>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}

        <br />
        <Button type="submit">Submit </Button>
      </form>

      <div className="output">
        <h2>Output</h2>
        <h3>Sizes:</h3>
        {sizeList &&
          sizeList.map((singleSize, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>{singleSize.size && <li>{singleSize.size}</li>}</ul>
          ))}

        <br />
        <h3>Color:</h3>
        {colorList &&
          colorList.map((singleSize, index) => (
            <ul key={index}>
              {singleSize.color && (
                <li>{singleSize.color + " - " + singleSize.colorStocks}</li>
              )}
            </ul>
          ))}
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, there was also a problem originally in the first textfield for `size`, I can't enter anything to it. But the values for colors and stocks are not duplicating anymore, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like below you wont have inputs with the same name

```
  name=`size${index}`
  id=`id${index}`
```

Comment: @N S Niko why is it showing 'JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text'?

Comment: Can you post your new code?